# Maze: Emoji Portals 2: Konchog's revenge

Tags: visual, mazes, emoji, network

Your Mission: get from START to EXIT.
There is only one route.
All portals, cells, and corridors are visited maximum once.

[image: Emoji Maze.]

Comment: I voted to close this as it's incomplete. I made a stupid mistake and should have tested the maze beforehand.  I really appreciate that @BeastlyGerbil still had a go with it, but it doesn't add much to this site, and I feel embarrassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is intended, but this may be a trick!

> [image]
>
> No portals are needed at all!

Comment: Grr!! I’m doing something wrong!! I will get this fixed properly rather than rush fix it ;-). 

Haha - I can go with “it was a trick question though” 

Comment: @Konchog if you can tell me the first emoji I will try and find the intended solution and add it too, but I'll need to know the first one as all of the emojis can be reached in the first square :P

Comment: that's so kind, but the maze is broken. I should really have checked it more carefully before posting.

Comment: @Konchog no issue, lesson for next time! At least there was still some solution and I wasn’t stuck trying to find one when there wasn’t any :P